# Does $f$ behave like $x^2$?

Tags: limits, functions

Let $f \in C^1([0, \infty))$ be a nondecreasing function such that

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^{2+\epsilon}}=0 \ \forall \epsilon>0$ and

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^{2-\epsilon}}= \infty \ \forall \epsilon>0$.

Then does the following hold?

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{x^{1+\epsilon}}=0 \ \forall \epsilon>0$ and

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{x^{1-\epsilon}}= \infty \ \forall \epsilon>0$.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain a counterexample simply by making $f$ regularly have sharp vertical spikes. For example, consider

$$ f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor^2 $$

This isn't continuous or differentiable, but you can modify it by replacing each jump discontinuity with a differentiable nondecreasing transition. No matter how you choose to make those transitions, your hypothesis will be satisfied.

However, the transitions themselves can be made as rapid as you like; you can arrange so that

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{x^{1+\epsilon}} $$

doesn't exist for *any* $\epsilon > 0$.